# Autodesk Design Automation Activities: How to distinguish between input and output parameters

Tags: autodesk, autodesk-designautomation

When creating a new activity, input and output parameters are not separated as it was need in v2. How does the design automation service distinguish between them?
Is it via the verb? I hope not, because sometimes there are poorly designed Rest-APIs or GraphQL endpoints that require a POST request for receiving data.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct!, it is via verb - based on type of verb, Design Automation service takes an action if it requires to download the resource (`get`) or upload the resource (`put` | `post`) etc, V3 also supports other types of verbs like `read`, `patch` etc.

Comment: Thank you. But for me this seems to be a very unfortunate decision of Autodesk.

Comment: Hi Julian, is this a theoretical concern or you are actually blocked? If you are blocked then I'd like to help. We could add an optional "direction" field to the parameter to unblock you.

Comment: This would be great. In fact it is more a theoretical concern. But actually I do have a GraphQL service that is providing some information I would need in a practical use case. Of course I could kind of proxy that with my "forge app" server, but that's not nice. In general it would be nice if I could define what is input and what output.

Comment: Yes, I agree. We are looking into providing in the coming months.